# AWS S3 Bucket Static Website Index/ Home Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So i have problem with AWS S3 Bucket Static when i try to access my domain without filename.

http://customdomain/ >> Error access denied

http://customdomain/index.html >> normal

but it's normal when i access it with default endpoint like

http://example.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ >>normal

what is the problem n solution? thank you

Comment: Probably configuring a default document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/IndexDocumentSupport.html